# AWS :edit the policy for s3 bucket-Your request exceeds one of the limits for this account

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When i try to edit s3 bucket policy for an IAM user i will get the following error

> Your request exceeds one of the limits for this account. Remove one or
>   more existing items and try again.

Currently i have 9 IAM users but when i edit the policy for other IAM users there is no problem occured

Here is my policy

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::assets.jobs.com/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::assets.jobs.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is for uploading files from php application

Comment: Does this error appear when you add an **Inline Policy** to the IAM User, or when you add an **existing policy** to the User? If you make a simpler policy, does it still error?

Comment: BTW, you can combine the actions into one grouping (except for `ListAllMyBuckets`) because they all refer to the same Resource.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein it ocurs when i add an inline policy to the exiting user

Comment: I just removed the  `{
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }` but still it gives the same error

Comment: Well, it must be something related to that user. Does the User have too many Inline Policies? You could create it as a **Policy** and then attach the Policy to the User (instead of an Inline Policy).

Comment: Nop there is only one policy  attached with him now i delted the policy and added again it works but IAM user can't access the contents in that bucket